# Global import in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, promise, bluebird

I basically want to replace the `Promise` definition in Typescript (v2.0.10) with Bluebird. I read a lot about this but came out confused -- is it possible or not?

I really don't want to have to do this at the top of every TS file:

```
import * as Promise from "bluebird";
```

I tried to do this in my `_stubs.d.ts` to no avail:

```
import * as Bluebird from "bluebird";
declare var Promise: typeof Bluebird;
```

Comment: You’re looking for [global augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation).

Answer (score 5):

1. `npm install --save-dev @types/bluebird-global`
2. Edit your `tsconfig.json` to list `bluebird-global` in the `types` array:

   ```
   {
     "compilerOptions": {
       "types": [
         "bluebird-global"
       ],
       // the rest of the options
     }
   }
   ```

---

Edit:

Step 2 is not necessary if you don't use the `compilerOptions.types` in your `tsconfig.json`.